# How to get a visualization of cross-app Spring Integration flow?

Tags: java, spring-integration, esb, microservices

We have a microservices architecture, i.e. each of the main components of our system is designed to be run as a separate Java app (jar or war).

We use Spring Integration to facilitate communication between the components (over a MQ service).

**How can we get a graphical diagram of the whole integration layer of the system, given that each component has its own Spring Integration XML config?**

Note that we know how to do it within a single application. The question is how to do it cross-app.

Example: 
Component 1 generates stream of POJOs -> MQ -> Component 2 serializes POJO object graph to JSON -> MQ -> Component 3 saves JSON to DB

Also, if a viable solution would be to create a single Spring Integration config, then how to make sure all components use it?

Comment: and how do you do this within a single application ?

Comment: Install Spring IDE plugin for Eclipse (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-ide) or Spring Tool Suite (https://spring.io/tools). Then open your Spring Integration XML config file. Then click "integration-graph". I have to admit though that the graph is not very pretty, or the tooling very user-friendly. For example, I can't figure out how to add new SI components despite labels like "Create [X]", etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This apparently can't be done easily at the moment.

My research brings me to the conclusion the only way is to use external tools:

- [New Relic Service Map](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.newrelic.com%2F2015%2F05%2F06%2Fservice-maps-ga%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFE1wcDqVmuHRZ2UopQA6NvuukIyQ) - Commercial. Probably only diagramming **running** microservice systems, because it's a monitoring system.
- [AppDynamics](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.appdynamics.com%2Fdevops%2Fvisualizing-and-tracking-your-microservices%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFCTE8fqtcF4Cf25sVxepT45vLgpA) - Commercial. Probably only diagramming **running** microservice systems, because it's a monitoring system.
- [Spigo](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fadrianco%2Fspigo&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGtwqU52EJVOzlAWuDNU5DplUysCA) - Open source. One could parse Spring Integration XML configs, generate input for Spigo, and generate a graph.
- [micro-infra-spring](https://github.com/4finance/micro-infra-spring/wiki/Service-discovery) - Open source. For diagramming **running** microservice systems. Requires ZooKeeper.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Twitter Zipkin and hopefully quite soon Spring Cloud Sleuth to trace it further on.